# BeautifulSoup parser fails on HTML-based R Markdown

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, r-markdown

I am trying to parse an R-Markdown with BeautifulSoup, in order to remove pieces of code that contain answers (it is for education). I have problems with code chucks that contain `<` or `>` operators, because BeautifulSoup identifies this as HTML. Is there a way to treat all code between the ``` regions in the example below as a single text string to avoid parsing it?

Here you can find a simple HTML example (`test.html`) that contains the problem:

````
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="code">
            ```{r}
            forcing.fun = function(time)
            {
              if(time<T1)
              {
                return(1)
              } else if(time<T2)
              {
                return(-0.1)
              } else
              {
                return(0)
              }
            }
            ```
        </div>
        <h1!>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
````

The failing parser is:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    html_data = html_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")
no_code = soup.find_all("div", "code")
for a in no_code:
    a.decompose()

output = str(soup)
print(output)
```

The incorrect output is:

```
<html>
<body>
</body></html>
```

while it should be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this:

```
if(time<T1) {
...
} else if(time<T2)
```

which being outside a `<pre>` tag are identified as (unproperly closed) tags, hence forcing the inclusion of the (actually malformed too) `h1` tag in the `div` (soup trying to close the "t1" 'tag' where it can).

You can't really blame Soup for this FWIW, parsing malformed html is garanteed to fail one way or another. I don't know what RMarkdown would make of this code, but if it does the right thing (either wrapping the code section in a `<pre>` tag or escaping the reserved characters to html entities), then you'd better first pass the code to RMarkdown and only then process the result.

Comment: I am not blaming anybody, I'd just like to know whether I can omit certain regions. The pre idea seems like a tempting solution.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `test.html` is not valid HTML, since characters like `<` and `>` are supposed to be escaped using `&lt;` or `&gt;`. So it's expected that BeatifulSoup would have trouble parsing the entire file.

So the best course would be to make sure that your input files have properly escaped HTML. However, you can use this hacky way to bypass this:

````
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.html', 'r') as html_file:
    html_data = html_file.read()

def encode_multiline_code(s):
    parts = s.split('```')
    ret = []
    for i,part in enumerate(parts):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            ret.append(part)
        else:
            ret.append(part.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'))
    return '```'.join(ret)

html_data = encode_multiline_code(html_data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")

no_code = soup.find_all("div", "code")
for a in no_code:
    a.decompose()

output = str(soup)
print(output)
````

This depends on the assumption that all the code is within blocks that start and end with ```` ``` ````, and this sequence does not appear in other places in the file.